# Eigenvalue problem $y'' + \lambda y = 0,$ $y'(0) = 0$, $y(1) = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions

> Find the eigenvalues of
>   $$y'' + \lambda y = 0, \; y'(0) = 0, y(1) = 0$$

For $\lambda >0$,

$$y(x) = c_1 \cos(\sqrt{\lambda} x) + c_2 \sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x)$$

We get that $y'(0) = 0 \implies c_2 = 0$, but when I try to solve for $\lambda$ when doing $y(1) = 0$, I run into trouble. Anyone know how to do this sort of problem?

Comment: The answer doesn't have trig functions in it. That's the equation $y"+y=0$ . By the way they are not eigenvalues. They just happen to be using $\lambda $.

Comment: @dylan7 This **is** an eigenvalue problem for the second-derivative operator.

Comment: Oh, yeah I see that now. My bad. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply your boundary condition at $x=1$:
$$
y(1)=c_1\cos(\sqrt{\lambda})=0\implies \sqrt{\lambda}={(2n-1)\pi\over 2},\ n=1,2,\dots
$$
(recall that the zeros of the cosine function occur at odd multiples of $\pi/2$), but then squaring both sides,
$$
\lambda=\lambda_n=\left({(2n-1)\pi\over 2}\right)^2,\ n=1,2,\dots
$$

Comment: This makes sense! Thank you. I have put up another post with a similar question, but more complicated boundary.